# Mapping String to Object in Angular

Tags: json, angular

I want to map a string to object (possibly same as JAVA does) in Angular.

json String: `{"policyNumber":"1234", "firstName":"archi"}`

Typescript Object :

```
export class ComplainDto {
  policyNumber: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  businessUnit: string     
}
```

In my TS i did following

```
export class LodgeComplainComponent {

  complainDto: ComplainDto;


  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.complainDto = new ComplainDto();

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log("params - "+params["complainData"]);
      if (params["complainData"] != '' && params['complainData'] != 'undefined') {
        this.complainDto = JSON.parse(params["complainData"]);
      }
      for (var key in this.complainDto) {
            console.log(key);
      }
    });
  }


}
```

complainDTO object has only two attribute (policyNumber and FirstName)
I want (policyNumber, firstName, lastName , businessUnit) to be attributes of complainDTO . as I have not passed last name and business Unit as part values of both should be null or empty

how can I do so that fields do not show for last name and business unit 'undefined'

```
  <div>
    <mat-form-field>
      <div>
      <mat-label>Policy Number</mat-label>
      <input matInput  [value]="complainDto.policyNumber"/>
      </div>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput [value]="complainDto.firstName"/>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput  [value]="complainDto.lastName"/>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div>
     <mat-form-field>
       <mat-label>Business Unit</mat-label>
       <input matInput  [value]="complainDto.businessUnit"/>
     </mat-form-field>
   </div>
```

Console log shows 
[image]

No other object attributes are created like lastName, businessUnit

Answer (score 0):

use the optional operator

```
[value]="complainDto?.lastName"
```

Comment: Still 'undefined' as I think Object did not have attribute lastName or BusinessUnit

Answer (score 0):

The properties on `ComplainDTO` are undefined until a value is set to them. You could initialize `complainDto` with all empty properties like this:

```
complainDto: ComplainDto = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  policyNumber: '',
  businessUnit: ''
};
```

However, the assignment of the parsed params overwrites the initialization and the `lastName` and `businessUnit` properties are undefined again. They would need to be manually assigned to after the params are assigned to either `null` or `''`.

```
if (params["complainData"] != '' && params['complainData'] != 'undefined') {
  this.complainDto = JSON.parse(params["complainData"]);
  this.complainDto.lastName = '';
  this.complainDto.businessUnit = '';
}
```

If there isn't a need to bind to `[value]`, the `complainDto` can be bound to `[(ngModel)]` without the safe navigation operator (?). The properties are still undefined but no value shows in the input until the user enters something.

```
<div>
  <input [(ngModel)]="complainDto.policyNumber"/>
</div>

<div>
  <input [(ngModel)]="complainDto.firstName"/>
</div>

<div>
  <input [(ngModel)]="complainDto.lastName"/>
</div>

<div>
  <input [(ngModel)]="complainDto.businessUnit"/>
</div>

<!-- Changes to the complain dto -->
<div>
  <pre>{{ complainDto | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

Initially, only the `firstName` and `policyNumber` properties are shown in the `json` pipe. But once the user starts typing, the other properties are added and a value assigned to them.

Here's a link to a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f2j9gm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) showing the `complainDto` being overwritten in the console and how two-way binding with `[(ngModel)]` works.